# Seleccionar un elemento de una web usando BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

http://ciudadmx.cdmx.gob.mx:8080/seduvi/fichasReporte/fichaInformacion.jsp?nombreConexion=cBenitoJuarez&cuentaCatastral=040_102_48&idDenuncia=&ocultar=1&x=-99.1616405&y=19.380011500000002&z=0.5

Hola buen dia, estoy tratando de extraer la informacion de esa pagina con python y BeautifulSoap, hasta ahora he conseguido extraer la parte del recuadro amarillo de abajo y filtrarlo, pero el recuadro de arriba me es imposible extraer la informacion filtrada.

La parte en negritas si puedo extraerlo, pero no entiendo como sacar el elemento que se encuentra debajo por que no tiene etiqueta de clase y no se como accesar , son 5 elementos y ya no doy mas. Alguna idea?

```
import urllib.request 
import bs4 as bs

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(html).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'html.parser')

for negritas in soup.find_all(class_ = "negritas"):
   print (negritas.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con nextSibling asi:

```
for negritas in soup.find_all(class_ = "negritas"):
  print (negritas.get_text())
  print (negritas.nextSibling.get_text())
```

Comment: Wow, increible funciono perfectamente muchisismas gracias.

Comment: Si te funciono, marca la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Una pregunta mas, si funciono la respuesta anterior y bastante bien pero tengo un problema, solo me interesan dentro de los elementos que tienen la clase_="negritas", 6 clases negritas con 6 siblings, como puedo seleccionar los 6 primeros elementos de negritas y los 6 siblings que les corresponden sin que corra toda la pagina?

Trate con esto pero no me deja :

soup.find_all("body", {'class':"negritas"})[2].getText()

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes utilizar un contador dentro de tu for loop, pero las respuestas no son para hacer otras preguntas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, perdon, hago un post sobre esa duda.